# Can I make the cursor bigger on the GNOME login screen?

Tags: gnome3, wayland, gdm3, accessibility

I'm running a GNOME/Wayland desktop environment on a Debian-based distro. When I'm logged in I have enabled *Large Text* and set *Cursor Size: Large*, both under Settings > Universal Access.

On the login screen, the Universal Access widget appears, allowing me to enable *Large Text* there too.

But there is no option to set *Cursor Size* on the login screen. How can I achieve this?