# Can I enable Night Light on the GNOME login screen?

Tags: gnome3, wayland, display-settings, gdm3

I'm running a GNOME/Wayland desktop environment on a Debian-based distro. When I'm logged in I have *Night Light* enabled.

There's a noticeable switch when logging in at night, as Night Light is only enabled once I'm logged in. It is also enabled on the unlock screen after I've logged in.

How can I enable Night Light on the first login screen, before I've logged in?

Comment: There's a half-moon symbol in the top right corner on GDM login screen, just turn it on. Works fine here.

Comment: not for me  would this be a gdm setting?

Comment: No but again, it's there only on machines with 3.22... The others that have the most recent 3.28 are missing the icon. BTW, [changing the mouse cursor size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437379/22142) doesn't work either although it should be as simple as running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 48` [while logged as the `gdm` user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361275/22142). File a bug report for both issues if you have the time.